# Machine Washable Sleeping Cot

Tags: tents, sleeping

I am looking for a machine washable sleeping cot (metal/aluminum frame off the ground). I have seen that most cots are made out of a water resistant material (nylon/polyester/canvas) 600D. I have seen that most cots are not listed as specifically machine washable; there are a few but they do not meet other requirements (price, size, color, height). If it matters, I am looking for an XXL. Most of my searches for "machine washable sleeping cot" return results for dog mats. To be clear, I am not talking about a washable "sleeping pad" that can go on top of the canvas.

Questions:

1. Does water resistance affect machine washability? I guess I've washed plenty of water resistant synthetic material before, but these may not be the same.
2. If it does not say machine washable, are there coatings or other reasons why Nylon/Polyester/Canvas 600D base material cannot be machine washed?
3. Is it more likely that a cot not listed as machine washable will be designed such that it might be too  difficult to quickly remove the nylon material from the frame? Or do they know people will possibly want to wash them?
4. Are there any modular options, wherein the nylon portion is not dependent on the frame, and can be purchased seperately depending in needs, mixed and matched, etc.
5. What has been you experience machine washing these types of products?

*Not sure if people are allowed to suggest products or manufacturers. The most promising appears to be the Teton Sports Outfitter XXL, but it is not listed as machine washable. Yes, I can contact the company myself.

Comment: Usually it's best to split questions like this up into separate questions.

Comment: I know, but it sounds like a lot of questions all related to the same topic. I'll wait a day and get back to it if still unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: The people have voted: They want an answer!

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, do you plan on sleeping directly on the cot? Usually if you aren't sleeping in a warm environment your underside could be cool. I always sleep with atleast a sheet on my cot, but what about you?

Comment: Probably with sheets... but I'd still like to wash the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Water resistance:  Yes it affects washability.  Water can't wet the surface.  Soap helps.  Gortex type coatings can get clogged pores, especially if not well rinsed.  Read the owners manual with care.

Coatings:  I washed a urethan coated nylon tarp.  The force of the water hitting the non-coated side started the coated side peeling.  After that I had to pitch at at least 30 degrees so that leaking water would cling and run down the slope.

Frame:  I've yet to see one that had a removable frame.  Mind you I haven't looked carefully. The original army cots required some dissassembly with tools to remove the frame.

Options:

A:  There is no reason I can see to use a coated fabric.  A medium weight nylon by itself should be sufficient.  You want it to breath anyway.  This may be a non-issue.

B:  If you can't find one, look at making one. 1" PVC pipe and furniture corners.  Nylon with grommets set in it every 6".  The nylon wraps around the frame and is laced on bottom.

C:  You may be able to wash one with a non-removable frame using a pressure washer at the car wash.

Finally, cots lack portability.  Certainly difficult to backpack.  If portability is a concern, consider hammocks as an option.  Not everyone's cup of tea.